# how to add imagebutton in asp.net linkButton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

How to do that dynamically C# ?

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="Server" >Text
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="Server" ImageUrl="~/images/Detail.png"></asp:ImageButton>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Forexample:

```
LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
lnk.Add(new ImageButton());
```

Comment: and what's wrong in your example? Just do that but also set ID, Text and other needed properties...

Comment: His example doesn't compile, that's what's wrong :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
var linkButton = new LinkButton() {
  ID = "LinkButton1"
};
linkButton.Controls.Add(new ImageButton() {
  ID = "ImageButton1",
  ImageUrl = "~/images/Detail.png"
});
```

Comment: @Penguen are you adding the `LinkButton` back to the original page?

Answer (score 1):

if its a LinkButton, Then you dont need to add an ImageButton into it

instead it'd be much better if you do it this way

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="MyLinkButton" runat="server" PostBackUrl="MyLink"><img src="MyImage" alt="MyLink" /></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `ImageButton` to the `Controls` collection:

```
LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
lnk.Controls.Add(new ImageButton()); //set your image button's properties first
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
lnk.Controls.Add(new ImageButton());
```

Comment: Frankly it is a pretty bizarre thing to want to do, what are you trying to achieve?